# Значения прототипов в Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Читаю книгу Дэвида Флэнагана (JavaScript. Подробное руководство). Встретился такой абзац:

> Объекты, созданные с помощью ключевого слова new и вызова
> конструктора, в качестве прототипа получают значение свойства
> prototype функции- конструктора. Поэтому объект, созданный выражением
> new Object(), наследует свойства объекта Object.prototype, как если бы
> он был создан с помощью литерала в фигурных скобках {}. Аналогично
> прототипом объекта, созданного выражением new Array(), является
> Array.prototype, а прототипом объекта, созданного выражением new
> Date(), является Date.prototype.

Провела тест:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно: прототип объекта, созданного как new Date() вообще не является Date.prototype. Вопрос: что Флэнаган здесь подразумевает как "прототип созданного объекта"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prototype` - это, как бы, хранилище общих свойств для всех экземпляров объекта.
Т. е. реализации его могут и не иметь (разве что они сами хотят быть предками).

Почти у всего есть свойство `__proto__`, которое указывает на это самое хранилище, так работает прототипное наследование.

В примере: `date.__proto__` указывает на `Date.prototype`, откуда берёт свойства.
Но у `date` нет свойств в прототипе, поэтому и `prototype` нет.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно разделять *объекты*, и *функции-конструкторы*.

В цитате речь идет о вторых:

> в качестве прототипа получают значение *свойства prototype* **функции-конструктора**

Применительно к примеру: есть функция-конструктор `Date`, у нее есть свойство *prototype*, в котором находятся методы для работы с датой.

После выполнения: `var date = new Date()`, создается **объект** *date*.

У созданного объекта **нет** свойства `prototype`, поэтому вызов `date.prototype` возвращает *undefiend*, как и обращение к любому другому отсутствующему свойству.

Для получения прототипа у объекта, можно воспользоваться [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf), либо свойством [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), которое вызывает эту функцию внутри себя.

Немного примеров:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(date) === Date.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(date) === date.__proto__);

var array = [];
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(array) === Array.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(array) === array.__proto__);

var object = {};
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(object) === Object.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(object) === object.__proto__);
```